# I want to insert image in xlsx sheet. Well i am creating sheet using ExcelJS.stream.xlsx.WorkbookWriter

Tags: javascript, exceljs

```
const workbook = new ExcelJS.stream.xlsx.WorkbookWriter(options);
// creating workbook 
const sheet = workbook.addWorksheet('Sheet1');
// creating sheet 

const barCodeLink = 'https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img922/7971/R0aEUe.jpg';
const barCodeResponse = await axios.get(barCodeLink, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' });

const base64BarCodeImage = Buffer.from(barCodeResponse.data, 'binary').toString('base64');
const barCodeId = workbook.addImage({
  base64: base64BarCodeImage,
  extension: 'jpg'
});

const barCodeDimensions = {
   width: 1.51 * inchesToPixels,
   height: 0.32 * inchesToPixels
};
const topRightCell = sheet.getCell('Q4');
topRightCell.alignment = { horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'top' };

sheet.addImage(barCodeId, {
  tl: { col: topRightCell.col, row: topRightCell.row },
  ext: { width: barCodeDimensions.width, height: barCodeDimensions.height }
 });
```

I am trying to insert image in sheet. But sheet.addImage is not a function.
when i try to insert image using while creating sheet using new ExcelJS.Workbook() it works fine.

Comment: Could you make a working fiddle with the sample code?

Comment: Sorry i can't. I have provided the sample code.